# is_singular() in mu-plugins not working

Tags: plugins, php, posts, filters, mu-plugins

I wanted to use mu-plugins to load the plugin only on a page with a single blog post. Unfortunately, the is_singular('post') function is not working properly. So I tried using $post->post_type, but also without success.

How do I check in mu-plugins if the currently displayed page is of type "post"?

```
function disable_plugin_func( $plugins ){
    
    if( !is_singular( 'post' ) && !is_admin() ) {
        $key = array_search( 'quiz-maker/quiz-maker.php' , $plugins );
        if ( false !== $key ) {
            unset( $plugins[$key] );        
        }
    } 
    
    return $plugins;
}
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugin_func' );
```

Comment: Completely deactivating the plugin is a very blunt approach. What does this plugin do? Why do you need to deactivate it for posts?

Answer (score 1):

When the `active_plugins` option is retrieved, WordPress does not yet know what page has been requested, so this approach will not work.

In order to achieve your objective, you would selectively activate the plugin (rather than selectively deactivate the plugin), but this may cause problems and destabilize your site (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', static function ( $plugins ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $plugins;
    }

    $key = array_search( 'quiz-maker/quiz-maker.php', $plugins );

    if ( false === $key ) {
        return $plugins;
    }

    unset( $plugins[ $key ] );

    return $plugins;
} );

add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    if ( ! is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Code to load the plugin.
} );
```

It's very likely this will not work. In which case, you'll need to reach out to the plugin author with your request, which, in my experience, they're likely to ignore.

Comment: In my experience, these types of optimizations rarely work. You're going to have better success selectively removing callbacks from actions than you will selectively loading a plugin.